# HBase scale up limitations

Tags: hbase, scaling

I'm new to HBase and have some questions about scaling up nodes:
- Is it possible to scale up one single node in a region or it is necessary that all nodes (except the region server) have the same resources.
- Is there any procedure to scale nodes or I just 'disconnect' the node from the cluster and reconnect it afterwards?

I can't give specific information about any deployment because I'm just learning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Scaling up only one node in HBase cluster have no meaning. Suppose, some of your RegionServers experiencing increased load and you scale up this particular server. During time, Master can perform load balancing and move regions which create biggest load to this server to another RegionServer.  And you in trouble again:)

And yes, to scale node, you can disconnect it, increase server resources and join it again. RegionServer as it own not storing data, it access data on HDFS. During server maintenance, regions belong to this server will be reassinged to other nodes(all data will be accessible).